# PHP массив с русскими ключами

Tags: php

Некий метод в системе возвращает массив с русскими ключами и строками в значения.

```
<?
echo $ar['Объект2']['Ид'];
?>
```

выводит значение ключа, перебором foreach не могу добиться вывода. Чем его перебрать? array_values() не помог.

Сам массив:

```
(
[Объект2] => Array
    (
        [Ид] => 142df7ae-643c-11e6-8fce-90e2ba539898
    )

[Объект3] => Array
    (
        [Ид] => 142df7b4-643c-11e6-8fce-90e2ba539898
    )
)
```

Comment: а как именно вы перебирали foreach-ом?

Comment: foreach ($arXMLElement as $key => $kom) {}

Comment: а почему $arXMLElement а не просто $ar, как в выше указанном коде

Comment: Работает: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a59b12d9577c2dcbc9cae62f264613a78eaacd3b ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: Я уже с кода копировал)

Comment: Блин, бред у меня не показывает

Comment: gettype() говорит массив, внутри массив и не объекты. И какова!!

Comment: @Роман20, а должны быть объекты?

Comment: Нет, просто массив

Comment: Вообще, обычным foreach'ем и перебирать )

Comment: А ты точно массив перебираешь ? а не XML объект, посмотри он instanceof Traversable

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в кодировках.

Comment: Согласен с вышесказанным - var_dump сделать массива и проверить кодировку.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array(
'Объект2' => array('Ид' => '142df7ae-643c-11e6-8fce-90e2ba539898'),
'Объект3' => array('Ид' => '142df7b4-643c-11e6-8fce-90e2ba539899')
);

foreach ($result as $value) {
    $arr[] = $value['Ид'];
}
echo "<pre>",var_dump($arr);
```